Foreign key to historized table
I like to store my current data along with historic data.  I did the following:
CREATE TABLE version (
  sn   serial PRIMARY KEY,
  id   int    NOT NULL,
  del  timestamp,
  name text,
  UNIQUE NULLS NOT DISTINCT (id, del)
);

sn is the key selecting both current and historic data. id is the key selecting only the current data. This works because NULLS NOT DISTINCT allows only one NULL value.  So the row where del is NULL is the current value.
I can create rows:
INSERT INTO version (id, name) VALUES (1, 'first');

And update them by marking the old as deleted and inserting an additional row:
UPDATE version SET del = now()::timestamp WHERE id = 1 AND del IS NULL;
INSERT INTO version (id, name) VALUES (1, 'second');

This works fine:
 sn | id |            del            |  name  
----+----+---------------------------+--------
  1 |  1 | 2024-05-27 12:57:16.34936 | first
  2 |  1 |                           | second

But referencing is a bit awkward.
CREATE TABLE latest_version(
  id  int       NOT NULL,
  del timestamp CHECK (del IS NULL),
  FOREIGN KEY (id, del) REFERENCES version(id, del)
);

It is necessary to maintain an empty del column.  Is there any way to get rid of this useless column?
I tried this, but it does not work:
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS latest_version CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE latest_version(
  id int NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (id, NULL) REFERENCES version(id, del)
);

Is there any other way to restrict the foreign key to those rows where del is NULL?

What is latest_version meant to store, and what should the cardinalities of its relationship to version be?

@Bergi The table latest_version is just a foobar table for anything referencing the latest (del is null) row in version. Cardinality should be n to 1. Another example may be a person table with mutable forename and surname gets referenced by some accounts belonging to the person. The accounts should reference the id of the person and not the sn enumerating the history of the person.

You might want a person table with the ids as the primary key, the have person_versions reference that, as well as have accounts reference it. If you still want a relation that contains both the current and old values, build a view that uses a union.

@Bergi Yes but then I have for each entity two tables: one for the immutable attributes and one for the mutable attributes. This might be the "best" design. I am just wondering if I can get this with just one table per entity.

I don't think so, and imo person versions would be considered a different entity as they have a different primary key. When creating a foreign key you'd have to decide which one to reference, and when writing a query you'd have to decide which to select from. If you don't like having to declare the same set of attributes on two tables, table inheritance could help, or (if you don't want to enforce that a person has a latest version) you could still store the data in the version table only and have only an id column in the person table.

Create latest_version without a reference and make sure that version.id is a foreign key referencing latest_version. You have an 1:n relation, that is, ONE latest_version corresponds to 0 or more records in version, hence version is the table that needs to reference latest_version, because the foreign key you wanted to define cannot uniquely identify the record by version.id, because this value is duplicated across multiple records.

I suggest you to create latest_version  as a VIEW :
CREATE VIEW latest_version AS
(SELECT * FROM version WHERE del IS NULL) ;

Then you can reference the VIEW like a table in any kind of query :
SELECT * FROM latest_version

see demo in dbfiddle

Afaik it is not possible to create a foreign key referencing a view.
